# How to set a background to an element from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, background-image

I am trying to to set a specific background for several buttons that I have grabbing an image from a json file. I am trying to apply the css "background" property to it to accomplish this through javascript, but am unsure how to do this. I tested out the current code that I have with simply the color "red", and this works just fine but when i try to pull it from a json file, there are no results. Any help on what I might do to approach this? here is my code:

```
   const t = "js/test.json"
   fetch(t)
      .then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (jsonObject) {
         var color = jsonObject['color'];
         for (var i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
            var buttonColor = i;
         if (buttonColor == 0 ) {
            document.querySelector(".btn").style.background= color[0].image;
         }


         }
      });
```

and the JSON file I am pulling the image from:

```
{
    "color":[
        {
            "name": "red",
            "image": "colors/red.png",
            "small-image":"colors/red-small.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "blue",
            "image": "colors/blue.png",
            "small-image":"colors/blue-small.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "yellow",
            "image": "colors/yellow.png",
            "small-image":"colors/yellow-small.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "green",
            "image": "colors/green.png",
            "small-image":"colors/green-small.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

The line I mostly need help with is on line 11, where

```
document.querySelector(".btn").style.background= color[0].image;
```

is found.

Comment: "colors/red.png" this is not a valid color

Comment: I want to set it so it uses the image instead of an actual color. In css you can set any image as the background with "background" or "background-image", I am just trying to figure out how to implement this with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the backgroundImage property instead

```
 document.querySelector(".btn").style.backgroundImage = `url(${color[0].image})`;
```

*Note:* the path to your file must be correct so now it will look if there is a directory colors and if inside this directory is a png named red.png.

Answer (score 1):

To set a background image instead of a color, you need to wrap the path to the image into url() function.
So, instead of doing:

```
document.querySelector(".btn").style.background = color[0].image;
```

you should do:

```
document.querySelector(".btn").style.background = `url(${color[0].image})`;
```